# Continuity of unique solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $G$, where $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set containing $I \times [a,b]$ where $I:=[x_0-d,x_0+d]$, for some $a,b,d \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a<b$ and $d>0$.

Suppose that $\forall t \in [a,b]$, the initial value problem $g'(x)=f(x,g(x)) \wedge g(x_0)=t$ has a ***unique*** solution for $g:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (differentiable up to the endpoints of $I$), which we will call $F(t):=g$.

Is $F:[a,b] \rightarrow C(I)$ always a continuous mapping, where $C(I)$ refers to the continuous functions on $I$ with metric $\rho(f,g):=\sup{\{|f(t)-g(t)|:t \in I\}}$?

Specifically, do we need an extra condition that $G$ contains the entire strip $I \times \mathbb{R}$?

If we have that extra condition, then we can show that $R:=\{F(t):t\in [a,b]\}$ is uniformly bounded, equicontinuous and closed. So it is compact, and then as $F^{-1}$ is continuous, it follows that $F$ is also continuous.

(Note: I do not have the condition that $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall (x,y_1),(x,y_2)\in G$, we have $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\le M|y_1-y_2|$, which is the usual Lipschitz condition.)

Comment: And the topology in $C^\infty(I)$ is...?

Comment: $C^\infty(I)$ is the metric space of all continuous functions on $I$ with metric $\rho(x,y)=\text{sup}{\{|x(t)-y(t)|:t \in I\}}$. Sorry, I forgot that it is not a standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

With the [usual (k-Lipschitz) condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) if $g_t$ is the solution with initial condition $t$,
$$\|g_t(x)-g_s(x)\|\le K\|t-s\|.$$

(for another $K$ that depends only of $k$ and the interval), i.e.,
$$\rho(g_t,g_s)\le K\|t-s\|.$$
See, for example, [Differential Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395120330) by Henry Cartan, II.1.10.

Comment: I don't have the Lipschitz condition on $f$, but what is given is that there are solutions and the solutions are unique. So I'm asking whether there is a counter-example. If $G$ contains the entire strip $I\times \mathbb{R}$, then I think I have a correct proof of this.

Comment: @user1537366, post your proof.

Comment: The formal proof is really long to type out, so I only edited the question to give the idea of the proof.